# How to make a double-newline?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to print in the Terminal something like this:

```
lollipop
lollipo
lollip
lolli
loll
lol
lo
l
```

However if i do -n twice i get a newline and then it just prints "-n" if i use echo. How can i  avoid this from happening and make this mess not print when i run X:

```
lollipop
lollipo-nlollip-nlolli-nloll-nlol-nlo-nl
```

X:

```
echo lollipop -n lollipo -n lollip -n lolli -n loll -n lol -n lo -n l
```

Comment: Use printf instead:

`printf "lollipop\nlollipo\nlollip\nlolli\nloll\nlol\nlo\nl"`

Comment: It would be clearer if you could add spaces, like this: printf "\\\lollipop\nlollipo\nlollip\nlolli\nloll\nlol\nlo\nl\\\"

Comment: Why `echo` and not something better?

Comment: People are downvoting this for what? The fact it uses echo? My last post had around 15 upvotes and the accepted answer 30 upvotes and it mostly used echo.

Comment: Side note: `-n` *removes* the trailing newline, it doesn't add it. And the main problem is even if it added it, you pass a single string to `echo`.

Comment: For not allowing commands other than `echo`. Nobody cares what your last post was. It's this post that's getting the downvotes.

Comment: Alright, i've cleared it up a bit.

Comment: @EddieDunn can you undelete your answer? `printf` is the way to go.

Comment: Muru: However, his answer doesn't have spaces between the codes and i saw the last "l" was like i would do "echo -n l", it's right behind the $.

Comment: @StarOS that can be fixed. Doesn't change `printf`'s suitability for `print`ing `f`ormatted text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the -e "enable interpretation of backslash escapes" option with the \n to force newlines

```
echo -e "lollipop\nlollipo\nlollip\nlolli\nloll\nlol\nlo\nl"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use printf instead:

`printf "lollipop\nlollipo\nlollip\nlolli\nloll\nlol\nlo\nl"`

Comment: "using echo" I'll change everything if i see this works.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer high level and portable tools for special formatting instead of such tools as echo. Here I am using AWK to print the ever decreasing substring that was provided with `here-string` . Note that I could have used `printf "%s" lollipop | awk . . .` as well for better portability

```
$ awk '{for(i=length($1);i>=1;i--) print substr($1,1,i)}' <<< "lollipop"       
lollipop
lollipo
lollip
lolli
loll
lol
lo
l
```

AWK's print function always prints a single line, similar to java's `System.out.println`. This could be replaced with `print "%s\n",substr($1,1,i)`

Comment: Hey, it works too.